# How to animate a swing motion in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

So I want to make a swing but the code I have right now is working..in reverse, if that is the right comparison, here is how it is supposed to look:
[image]

Sorry for the crappy doodle but I think it would be easier than explaining what I want and what I have.

So the code I am using is:

```
if (s == 0)
{
    group.rotation.x -= ctrl.boxStep;
    if (group.rotation.x < -.6)
    {
        s = 1;
    }
}
else
{
    group.rotation.x += ctrl.boxStep;
    if (group.rotation.x > .6)
    {
        s = 0;
    }
}
```

But as you see in the doodle it is not working the right way and I am not sure how to change the group's movement for it to look like a swing motion.

Any ideas that someone could suggest?

Comment: Are you using threejs?

Comment: Your group is the center of rotation. Currently, its center is at the seat, which is why the rotation is applying as you're seeing it. Apply local transformations to the rope and seat such that the top of the rope is at the center of the group. Then the rotations should work as expected. If you need further help, you'll need to give us more code for how you're constructing your scene.